# Setting part of title as bold and normal in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, text

I want to create an axis title that has part of it in bold font.

This is an example of my current code:

```
# Features to plot
features = ['Overall Rating', 'Shooting Rating', 'Creativity Rating', 'Passing Rating', 
            'Dribbling Rating', 'Defending Rating', 'Pressing Rating', 'Aerial Rating']

# Loop through each feature and create density plots
for i, feature in enumerate(features):
    ax = axes[i]
    # Draw the density plot using the current feature column from the DataFrame
    sns.kdeplot(df[feature], shade=True, color='white', ax=ax)
    # Plot marker for df
    player_value = df[feature].values[0]
    ax.set_title(f'{feature}\n{int(player_value)}', color='#100097', loc='right', fontweight ="bold")
```

I want the text for `feature` to be a normal font weight, and for `player_value` to be a bold font weight.

I've tried various methods to no avail: creating a separate title for each section of text, trying to set the fontweight separately within the `set_title` function, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***LaTeX***** to achieve this, quite easily using this kind of expression: `$\\bf{bold text}$"`. In this case, the "bold text" will be displayed as bold.

So in your case, add this:

```
ax.set_title(f'{feature}\n$\\bf{{{int(player_value)}}}$', color='#100097', loc='right')
```

**: about LaTeX, it seems MathText is what is being called and not LaTeX, I will edit my question later

Comment: This is great thanks! Is it also possible to change the size of the font only for the `player_value`?

Comment: Maybe... let me check

Comment: @codemachine98 where are you plotting (which IDE) or are you using console?

Comment: @codemachine98 it seems mathtext is what is being called in matplotlib and not LaTeX. I'll figure something else out, but maybe better to close this question and ask another one to get more attention on your second question. https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/mathtext.html

Comment: @codemachine98 it is quite buggy to use latex and matplotlib, I haven't done it so far and I always thought that it was already there :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by calling set_title for two different locations (eg loc='left' and loc='center').

This:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

feature = 'Overall Rating'
player_value = 100
ax.set_title(f'{feature}', color='#100097', loc='left', fontweight='normal')
ax.set_title(f'{int(player_value)}', color='#100097', loc='center', fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

Gives:

[image]

You can also set font size. For example:

```
ax.set_title(f'{feature}', color='#100097', loc='left', fontweight='normal', fontsize=14)
ax.set_title(f'{int(player_value)}', color='#100097', loc='center', fontweight='bold', fontsize=20)
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: while this is nice, the two titles are separate objects, so not really what OP asked, I think at least